# Attempting to star a chat message from the star wall while not logged in causes "An error occurred performing this action"

Tags: bug, chat, chat-stars, 404-not-found

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open any chat room while not logged in or in Incognito Mode.
2. Attempt to star a message in the star wall.
3. Observe that the "An error occurred performing this action" overlay is shown as the POST request to `http://chat.stackoverflow.com/messages/33607417/star` has failed with 404 Not Found.

Reproduced on Chat.SO and Chat.SE.

Mac OS 10.11.6 (15G1108)

Google Chrome Version 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit)

Comment: @HDE226868 Then the message should say "log in to star messages" instead of "An error occurred performing this action."  Or the system shouldn't let you star messages if you are not logged in.

Comment: The bug is that the star is clickable in the star wall. In the messages themselves it's not clickable.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes that's it, thank you for clarifying.

Comment: well... an error *did* occur - what's the issue?